# Can I display the image from a camera on a plane in the same scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

OK - I have a small spacecraft with limited vision inside. The spacecraft is racing against others. I want a holopanel to either side of the pilot, displaying what is to either side of the craft. It this possible in the scene? I want to try and avoid faking it in post if I can.

I will be rendering in Cycles as a short video.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think  Blender is capable of render two cameras **in the same process**.

But you can make the light from the sides reaching the camera in the old way: make a hole in the ship and bend the rays by 90° (with a mirror).

[image]

In the picture above you can see Suzanne in a whaleish vehicle with some other smaller spaceships (red, yellow and green) on both sides.

[image]

*Anyway I think it would be easier to put two cameras and composite the holograms in post. You'll surely have much more control on their final appereance.*